# Zero Config jQuery Datatable default pagination not working for large table

Tags: jquery, datatables

**Caveat:**

I know I should be doing server-side pagination , ajax loading etc. That's for another day.

**Problem:**

I have a simple (static,hard-coded) table with 3 columns and about 5000 rows. I apply `Datatable` to it with zero config. The pagination doesnt work. It shows showing 10 rows while actually showing everything.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" id="listtable" class="data-table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed ">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Employee</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td> <a href="aaaaaa" class="txt-reallyred"> xxxxxxx </a> </td>
         <td>yyyyyyyy</td>
         <td>zzzzzzzzz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> <a href="aaaaaa" class="txt-reallyred"> xxxxxxx </a> </td>
         <td>yyyyyyyy</td>
         <td>zzzzzzzzz</td>
      </tr>
 ... repeat about 5000 times
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#listtable").DataTable();
```

**JSFiddle with problem (wait about 5-6 secs for the datatables to kick in):**

https://jsfiddle.net/d06ju3an/1/

Comment: i can confirm it doesnt work#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the HTML, you close and open the `tbody` tag twice.

```
[...] <td>zzzzzzzzz</td> </tr> </tbody> <tbody> <tr> <td> [...]
```

If you use the filter input you'll see DataTables works, but only in the first `tbody` tag.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d06ju3an/19/)

Comment: Yikes, copy paste error. Sorry and thanks. Ill delete the question since it provides no value.